# Download source from google code

Tags: svn

I am not sure how to download the code fro the google source code this is the page that it shows when i go there and i follow these instructions over here
http://engtech.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/howto_google_code_hosting_subversion_tortoisesvn/
but still unable to get the source code as I am not able to find the link that i have to use to download.

http://code.google.com/p/andres-development-resource/source/checkout

Comment: Since the page says it is using Mercurial, it doesn't make much sense to be following instructions for SVN.

Comment: @Quentin sorry man i am new to all this subversioning thingy.. tks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andres-development-resource/
```

This is a Mercurial command, so you need **[Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/)**, not SVN, to download (clone) that repo.

You can use also, if you want an equivalent for TortoiseSVN, **[TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/)**:

[image: TortoiseHg menu]